# How to best DRY with some ad-hoc class instances?

Tags: c++, initialization, idioms, type-deduction

Sometimes in my code, I find myself wanting to define several instances of the same class, with the difference in the definition being small relative to its overall length, and sharing some common designator. And - I struggle to refactor the code so that it's both compact and easy to use.

Example: I start with:

```
auto blue_foo = std::make_unique<float[]>(n);
auto blue_bar = std::make_unique<float[]>(m);
auto blue_baz = std::make_unique<float[]>(k);
```

This is kind of icky: Repetition of commands and name prefixes... :-(

I can put this these variables in a struct named `blue`, so that I could write

```
do_stuff_with(blue.foo, blue.baz, 123);
```

rather than

```
do_stuff_with(blue_foo, blue_baz, 123);
```

but - then I would need even *more* repetition:

```
struct {
    std::unique_ptr<float[]> foo, bar, baz;
} blue = {
    std::make_unique<float[]>(n),
    std::make_unique<float[]>(m),
    std::make_unique<float[]>(k),
};
```

So wasteful! I would have at least liked to write something like:

```
struct { auto foo, bar, baz; } foo = {
    std::make_unique<float[]>(n),
    std::make_unique<float[]>(m),
    std::make_unique<float[]>(k),
};
```

but that's not possible.

Also, I don't want to repeat the make_unique call. I could write a lambda, I suppose:

```
auto make_data = [](std::size_t size) { return std::make_unique<float[]>(size); }

struct { auto foo, bar, baz; } blue = { make_data(n), make_data(m), make_data(k) };
```

but the lambda is a lot of writing; and it doesn't save all that much. And even that has some repetition.

What is an idiomatic approach for maiing my initial piece of code compact and readable?

**Note**: In the example, the code snippet is not repeated many times; just once. If I repeatedly used a combination of foo, bar and baz I would write a class for holding them.

Comment: compact but very inefficient: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a9da1191bd1b9c3

Comment: @user12002570 : You commented and answered making basically the same point; see my reply to your answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Hmm, do like the scripting languages do... interesting. Although it doesn't quite go all the way, since you repeat the float_vec ctor many times.

Comment: @einpoklum I appreciate their flexibility, even though it comes at a cost.

Comment: @einpoklum Unfortunately (fortunately?) the vector constructor is explicit so the type has to be repeated.  If you are doing this in a lot of places you could make your own vector class to be used in these situations since you aren't using any of the vector operations, just leveraging the dynamic size construction

Comment: @einpoklum: This question feels like a misunderstanding of what DRY is. DRY is about eliminating repetition for information that is knowable at the site of the repetition. There is no relationship between these variables. In your head they may all be "the same type" and are initialized with very similar expressions, but there is no syntactic relationship between them that would create such a relationship. As such, they are not repeating information; you're just specifying what needs to be specified. It just so happens that this information is the same for these different circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest (but not necessarily most readible) version that I could come up with is using a variadic template immediately invoked lambda:

```cpp
#include <memory>

int main() {
    auto blue = [](auto... ns) {
        struct { 
            std::unique_ptr<float[]> foo, bar, baz; 
        } ret { std::make_unique<float[]>(ns)... };
        return ret;
    }(1, 2, 3);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9c8cvc8oW

It doesn't have any repetitions, but I am not sure you would call it idiomatic.

You can simplify this and improve readibility if you are ok with using `new` instead of `std::make_unique` and repeating `new float[x]` three times:

```cpp
#include <memory>

int main() {
    struct { 
        std::unique_ptr<float[]> 
            foo{new float[1]}, 
            bar{new float[2]}, 
            baz{new float[3]}; 
    } blue;
}
```

Comment: It has to have each name next to each parameter, it's not good that they're separate like that. But +1 for the idea, maybe I can adapt it further.

Comment: Then please add this requirement to your question.

Comment: I added an alternative to the answer. Note that you can use `std::make_unique` instead of `new float`, whatever you prefer, the version with `new` is just shorter.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific example, all members have the same type, which makes `std::array` a viable option:

```cpp
using array_type = float[];
auto [foo, bar, baz] = std::array{
    std::make_unique<array_type>(n),
    std::make_unique<array_type>(m),
    std::make_unique<array_type>(k),
};
```

This eliminates most of the repetition, but `std::make_unique` still gets called thrice.
For smaller examples, you could solve this as follows:

```cpp
constexpr auto make = [](std::size_t size) { return std::make_unique<float[]>(size); };
auto [foo, bar, baz] = std::array{make(n), make(m), make(k)};
```

For larger examples where even calling `make` multiple times is a problem, you can write something like:

```cpp
// reusable code
template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename F>
auto transform(std::array<T, N> data, F f)
  -> std::array<decltype(f(data[0])), N>
{
    return std::apply([&f](auto&... x) -> decltype(transform<T, N, F>(data, f)) {
        return { f(x)... };
    }, data);
}

// one-time code
constexpr  auto make = [](std::size_t size) { return std::make_unique<float[]>(size); };
auto [foo, bar, baz] = transform(std::array{n, m, k}, make);
```

You can go as far as obtaining the syntax  `transform({n, m, k}, make);` if you don't use `std::array`, but a `T(&data)[N]` parameter, similar to [`std::to_array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/to_array).

Answer (score -1):

You can make a helper function that returns `std::tuple` of `unique_ptr` and then use [structure bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding). The general idea is as follows:

```
auto make(float n, float m, float k)
{ 
 return std::tuple{std::make_unique<float[]>(n), std::make_unique<float[]>(m), std::make_unique<float[]>(k)};
} 
    
auto [blue_A, blue_B, blue_C] = make(n,m, k);
```

Comment: You've mis-understood the question. That definition code only occurs _once_, i.e. your `make` function would only ever be called once. That means it doesn't save me anything: Neither typing, nor repetition, nor complexity, nor use of the `blue_` prefix.

Comment: @einpoklum Then the question is very unclear.

Comment: Nathan Oliver got it; anyway, added a clarifying notw.

Answer (score -2):

@NathanOliver makes the interesting suggestion of using a dictionary / `std::map`. But that still makes me repeat a bunch of code. If we have a let with an appropriate transformer of key-ctor-arguments pairs to key-contructed-values pairs, and if we could instantiate it withput any template ambiguity issues, that might let us write:

```
dict<std::make_unique<float[]>> blue { 
    { "foo", n }, 
    { "bar", m },
    { "baz", k }
};

do_stuff_with(blue["foo"], blue["baz"], 123);
```

Benefits:

- No repetition of anything; specifically, we only need a single templated definition of dict for all such cases in all programs.
- No artificial prefixing
- Can pass all of `blue` together

Detriments:

- Haven't actually implemented this to establish it works...
- More mental load on reader of this code
- Bespoke class, not in the standard library
- Performance overhead in the code that uses it